# What is the smallest degree of polynomial so that its graph includes four extreme points

Tags: polynomials

Let there be four points `(-2,-5), (5,-6), (6,1), (-1,2)` that are extrema (maxima / minima). I am trying to find a polynomial that includes these extreme points. I tried

```
p[x_] = Sum[c[i] x^i, {i, 0, 7}]; 
p[x] /. Solve[{p[-2] == -5, p[5] == -6, p[6] == 1, p[-1] == 2, 
           p'[-2] == 0, p'[5] == 0, p'[6] == 0, p'[-1] == 0}, {c[0], c[1], 
           c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7]}]
```

> ```
> {-(112909/16464) - (1227475 x)/98784 + (1360085 x^2)/592704 +
>   (6599065 x^3)/1185408 - (292265 x^4)/296352 - (310447 x^5)/592704 +
>   (13175 x^6)/84672 - (13175 x^7)/1185408}
> ```

What is the smallest degree of a polynomial so that its graph includes the four points as extrema?

Comment: You have 8 conditions, therefore you need a polynomial with 8 parameters, that is a 7 degree polynomial.

Comment: @DanielHuber Well, that's the general case which holds "almost always" (in the mathematical sense). It could have a lower degree for some constraints (quite obviously). One could use `Exists` and such to figure out constraints on these constraints to succeed with a lower degree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Use the form `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{x1,f[x1],f'[x1]},{x2,f[x2],f'[x2]},...}]`
- We use `f[x]==y,f'[x]==0,f''[x]!=0` to verify the extreme points.

```
Clear[pts, data, f];
pts = {{-2, -5}, {5, -6}, {6, 1}, {-1, 2}};
data = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ pts;
f[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[data, x] // Expand
f /@ pts[[;; , 1]] == pts[[;; , 2]]
f' /@ pts[[;; , 1]]
f'' /@ pts[[;; , 1]] != 0 // Thread
```

[image]

### Reply to comment

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 7}, Mesh -> {pts[[;; , 1]]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[LightGreen], Opacity[.8], 
   Polygon@pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: `{{-2, -5}, {5, -6}, {6, 1}, {-1, 2}}` is a square. How can I draw it and show it.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter  `pts = {{-2, -5}, {5, -6}, {6, 1}, {-1, 2}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[LightGreen], poly}]`

Comment: Draw in the same graph of `f[x]`?

Comment: Thanks. Let's me try.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter  I see it now. See  my updated.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried `Plot[f[x], {x, -2.5, 6.5}, Mesh -> {pts[[;; , 1]]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Orange], Opacity[.8], 
   Polygon@pts}]`

Comment: Set the `PlotRange` to get a better proportioned `Plot`, e.g., `PlotRange -> {-15, 10}`

Answer (score 3):

```
pts = {{-2, -5}, {5, -6}, {6, 1}, {-1, 2}};
derivs = {0, 0, 0, 0};
specs = MapThread[{{First@ #1}, Last@ #1, #2}&, {pts, derivs}];
InterpolatingPolynomial[specs, x] // Expand
```

[image: interpolating polynomial]

Comment: `f'[5]==-769/42`, not equal to 0. Similar to `f'[-2]`, `f'[6]`, `f'[-1]`

Comment: @Laurenso Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
val = {{-2, -5}, {5, -6}, {6, 1}, {-1, 2}};

 f = Interpolation[val]

 Series[f[x], {x, 0, 7}]
```

$$    \frac{51}{14}-\frac{37 x}{84}-\frac{25 x^2}{14}+\frac{25x^3}{84}+O\left(x^8\right)$$

```
  (f[#1] == #2 &) @@@ val 
  {True, True, True, True}
```